# Was the Sphere Hunt scene scene in the original publication of The White Mountains?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, the-tripods

There is a passage that seems to be present in some copies (or adaptations) of John Christopher's *The White Mountains*, the first book in the 1967–1968 *[Tripods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tripods)* trilogy, but which may not have been in the original novel.  The passage in question involves the appearance of two Tripods who ignore the three protagonists, will all their attention apparently devoted to a glowing golden sphere.  I do not remember this incident from the first time I read the *The White Mountains* in the 1980s.  The copy of the book that I read was quite worn, and it featured the oldest American cover design.  It could easily have been from the one of the earliest American printings.

[image: The White Mountains]

After reading all three books, I learned that the stories had been [serialized in graphic format](http://the-haunted-closet.blogspot.com/2010/03/white-mountains-boys-life-mar-1981-july.html) over four years in *Boy's Life* magazine, and I was interested in looking over the magazine's version of the story.  The oldest issue of *Boy's Life* that my elementary school had was from July, 1982, which featured the last installment from the *The White Mountains*.  When I looked through the issue, I was surprised to see an episode that I did not remember from the book.  Just before the three boys reach Mont Blanc, they meet two Tripods tossing a golden ball.

[image: Chapter 15 (top half of page)]

However, I think that when I read the book to my older son several years ago, the Sphere Chase scene was indeed not present in the text.  I concluded that Christopher may have added the scene for the *Boy's Life* version, to provide some enigmatic foreshadowing of kind of bizarre thing that Will would encounter in *The City of Gold and Lead*.  (And bizarre the Sphere Chase certainly is.  It is never explained by the Masters in *The City of Gold and Lead*, and Ruki in *The Pool of Fire* absolutely refuses to discuss it.)

Yet I just finished read the book again, to my younger son, and this time the Sphere Chase encounter was there!  I was not reading from the same physical book as last time; this was a fairly recent edition (from after the publication of the ill-conceived and datedly 1980s prequel *When the Tripods Came*):

> Of course, they were nothing like as close as they seemed.  There were miles of plain still, and then the foothills.  But at least we could see them, and we set out in good heart.  We had been traveling for an hour, and Henry and I were making jokes about Beanpole’s gigantic steam-kettle, when he stopped us.  I thought the jokes had annoyed him, but then felt, as he had already done, the earth quiver beneath our feet.
>
> They were coming from the northeast, from our left and behind—two Tripods, moving fast and heading directly for us. I looked around desperately, but knew what I would see. The land was green and flat, without a tree or rock, a hedge or ditch, and the nearest farmhouse was half a mile away.
>
> Henry said, “Shall we run for it?”
>
> “Run where?” Beanpole asked.  “It is no good.”
>
> His voice was flat.  If he recognized it was hopeless, I thought, then it was hopeless indeed.  In a minute or two they would be on us. I looked away from them to the gleaming battlements of white.  To have come so far, endured so much, and to lose with our goal in sight—it was unfair.
>
> The earth shook more violently.  They were a hundred yards away, fifty... They marched side by side, I saw, and their tentacles were doing strange things, probing and retreating from each other, describing elaborate patterns in the air.  And something moved between and above them, a golden something that flashed with brightness, tossed to and fro against the blue of sky.
>
> They were on us.  I waited for a tentacle to reach down and seize me, conscious less of fear than of a futile anger.  A great foot slammed down a few yards from us.  And then they were past, and going away, and my legs felt as though they were buckling.  Beanpole said, in wonder, “They did not see us.  Because they were too concerned with each other?  Some ritual of mating, perhaps?  But they are machines.  What then?  It is a puzzle to which I would like the answer.”
>
> He was welcome, I thought, both to the puzzle and its answer.  All I could feel was the weakness of relief.

So, what is the actual history of this passage?  Was it added to the text of the novel at some point (to provide the aforementioned foreshadowing)?  Is it a difference between the early British and American editions?

Comment: Probably your edition was just misprinted

Comment: The edition with the cover you give is available at the Internet Archive, and it does seem to have the passage about the golden ball https://archive.org/details/whitemountains00chri/page/210/mode/2up?q=golden

Comment: I have the old paperback with the same cover shown in the question. First Collier Books edition, 1970. It has the sphere tossing scene on page 211. The most reasonable explanation seems to be that you forgot about it.